# InventoryID on child record not updating when saving new item

Tags: acumatica

I have ARSalesPrice records on the InventoryItemMaintBase graph with some additional functionality included. When these sales prices are entered on a new item that hasn't been saved, I am getting the error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'InventoryID', table 'AC2021R1.dbo.ARSalesPrice';
column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

It seems that when the Inventory ID is assigned, it is not moving over to the ARSalesPrice. The inventory ID field on the ARSalesPrice DAC has a PXParent to the InventoryItem as well as a PXDBDefault attribute on the CacheAttached event. I was under the impression that would be all I needed. Do you know what I should be doing in order for the inventory ID to be assigned to the ARSalesPrice when it is saved for the first time?

CacheAttached:

```
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
    [PXParent(typeof(Select<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<ARSalesPrice.inventoryID>>>>))]
    [PXDBDefault(typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryID), DefaultForInsert = true, DefaultForUpdate = true)]
    protected virtual void _(Events.CacheAttached<ARSalesPrice.inventoryID> e)
    {

    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but have you also included a PXDBDefault on ARSalesPrice to populate the InventoryID from InventoryItem?  You can't just define a parent.  You have to do something to populate it.  Since you need it based on the parent DAC, you would use PXDBDefault instead of PXDefault.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to include the PXDBDefault attribute. For surety, you can specify the DefaultForInsert property to true or set this property at graph initialize through the PXDBDefaultAttribute.SetDefaultForInsert (see the https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/(W(5))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=680e01c8-6b98-74bb-ef73-b605e37c33f5)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried using the PXDBDefault attribute on the CacheAttached event, but that didn't work. I will update my question with that information. I also tried with and without DefaultForInsert and DefaultForUpdate, as well as PXDefault. I'm not sure why it isn't update the inventoryID on the ARSAlesPrice with the inventoryID from the InventoryItem...